# For loop, checking pairs that would be identical

Tags: c++, visual-c++, for-loop

I'm using a double for loop to loop through my list of objects and check if my bot at position i collided with the bot at position j. I successfully am checking for the ii, jj combinations and that those should not be done, but I'm looking to handle when the i,j occurs that j, i doesn't occur. Example, (1, 1) shouldn't happen, and its checked for however, (1,4), but when it reloops through, I **DONT** want (4,1) to occur.

Thoughts:

I thought a temp to hold when that occurs happens, however that bombs out when multiple collisions among multiple bots is occurring. Is there any way to avoid this issue? My question is not about modularity or the use of a double for loop.

```
   for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
      for(int j = 0; j < count; j++)
      {
         if(i != j)
         {
            if(vbot[i]->CollidedWith(vbot[j]))
            {

               vbot[i]->DoBattleWith(vbot[j]);
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the inner loop to

```
  for(int j = i + 1; j < count; j++)
```

and get rid of the `if` statement.

With these modifications, the code will only consider `(i, j)` pairs such that `i < j`.

Comment: I wasn't thinking in that way. Thank you. That makes alot of sense, if 3 is colliding with 5 then obviously 5 is colliding with 3 and theres no reason to ever check the (y,x) for each (x,y).

Comment: @WhyCry: Glad to be able to help. This is a very common pattern that shows up all the time, so it's useful to know.